# Summary statistics in shell script

Tags: shell-script, awk, files, statistics

I have multiple files (records) across multiple directories. Each record lies in its own path based on the date it was created.

Eg a record on 12 Nov 2016 is

```
~/records/2016/11/12/record.
```

In each record, there is a number in the final line and I am trying to calculate summary statistics for each year.

How do I write a script that takes two user inputs:

- year
- statistic

where statistic could be average, max, min or all (avg, max
   and min)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `year` input to define the root directory for a `find` command that searches all `record` files and calls `tail -1` for every file.

```
find ~/records/"$YEAR" -type f -name record -exec tail -1 {} \;
```

This would be sufficient to print all values of the specified year.

To calculate min/max/average pipe the output into `awk` for the calculation.

```
awk -v stat="$STATISTICS" 'BEGIN { count=0; sum=0; }
  { if(!count) { min=$0; max=$0; }
    count++;
    sum += $0;
    if($0 > max) max = $0;
    if($0 < min) min = $0;
  }
  END {
    if(count) {
      # TODO: use variable "stat" to select only one result to print
      print min;
      print sum/count; # average
      print max;
    } else {
      print "no data";
    }
  }'
```

You can combine and extend these snippets to get a complete script.